# What are the minimum specifications for Froyo?

Tags: android

What are the minimum specifications for Froyo... as CPU, memory, interfaces? I was searching all over the web, but I couldn't find anything that I need. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has documents for Android compability :

[Google Compability PDF](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/pt-PT//compatibility/android-2.3-cdd.pdf)